# Apache Flink with Hadoop HDFS: wrong FS expected file:///

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-flink

I have a custom Flink Sink, which is writing to HDFS, usin the following code to instantiate the FileSystem object.

```
val path = new Path("/path/to/one/hdfs/dir")

val hadoopJob   = Job.getInstance
val hadoopConf   = hadoopJob.getConfiguration
val fs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)
val os = fs.create(path)
```

I have set the property **fs.hdfs.hadoopconf** in the flink configuration file pointing to the directory where I have the hadoop configuration files.

In the core-site.xml I have defined the property ***fs.defaultFS*** as shown below.

```
 <property>
     <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
     <value>hdfs://hostname:port</value>
</property>
```

And it is failing because it is instantiating an object type LocalFileSystem, instead of DistributedFileSystem. Following is the exception I get.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://compute-0-0:9000/esteban.collado/kmers, expected: file:///
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:665)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:86)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:542)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:528)

Could anyone give me some clue about the possible issue ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are flink-runtime and the Hadoop libraries available on the classpath? Did you check the documentation at https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/filesystems/overview/ ?

Comment: yes, I have the jar files inside the FLINK_HOME/lib folder, and that part seems to be fine, because if I use this code "FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://compute-0-0:9000")," it works file, it instantiate the DistributedFileSystem class and works, but I was hoping to not have to do that, and let Hadoop and Flink take the correct configuration.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can look at the FileSystem.get(path) method, through path to identify the final file system
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/puPzC.png

Comment: yes, I am doing that "val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://compute-0-0:9000"), hadoopConf)", and it works doing it like that, but I was hoping I could make my code agnostic in that sense.